# Problems with SSRS report previewing different results than what the stored procedure is returning

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, rdl

I have Googled this issue I am having and there appears to be no one else who has had this problem.  I am working with SSRS 2012 with a main report and a subreport.  The subreport has 2 parameters:  one is a an account Number and the other is a date.  These are being passed into the subreport correctly, however the previewed results are different than what the stored procedure behind the subreport shows.

A picture says a 1000 words, so here is what the result of the stored proc looks like:
[DB stored proc results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OudrV.gif)

When I render just the subreport, I am getting this:
[RDL Preview Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq0PR.gif)

The only grouping being done is on the StateOfJurisdiction.  I have tried this with and without grouping.

It appears to be mixing the data in both rows. I have also cleared the RDL cache file just to be sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "When I render just the subreport, I am getting this....".  So the problem is unrelated to the main report then? Can you confirm that if you manually set the parameters in the sub-report and run it that you still see the inconsistency?

Comment: Run a trace using SQL profiler and compare the queries

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  You are correct.  I am 99.9% sure the problem is unrelated to the main report.  I have also checked the parameters being used and they along with the results are the same as when I run only the subreport by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after messing with this all night, I decided to create a new subreport and try that on for size.  It worked!  Not sure what that was all about, but I will have to later compare the RDL files to see what the smoking gun was.  Thanks though for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are testing your reports in Visual Studio. Visual Studio will cache database hits when you develop. To refresh with the latest data, either refresh your dataset or run the report and select the green refresh arrow, otherwise it will run from cache for the fore sable future.